# Facebook Like button with different image

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am implementing facebook like button. I had also implemented that successfully but my requirement is I want that like button to be appear on my image.For example :-

facebook button div :-

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I want this is to appear when user click on this :-

```
<img src="images/compliments.jpg" alt="Give compliments on car services Mumbai"/>
```

[image]
At present facebook show its own like image i want to use my image and when user click on this image it should like this page

I am implementing this for the first time and any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin."

That's basically Facebook saying you cant do that. Sorry

(Taken from http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you cant under any circumstances. It's against the Facebook Platform Policies.

Comment: @Dom I think it would be of value to point out what you pointed out, but then also go through how you would do it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is against the terms of Facebook, see https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts for a list.

Comment: Like I said, and several others as well, this is not allowed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in your stylesheet.

```
.fb-like { 
 background-image: url("images/compliments.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is completely against Facebook's terms and conditions - you are not allowed to change the appearance of the logos and/or buttons at all, other than as detailed within the developer API