# Trigger / send a click event from another html element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Via firebug or chrome I could look into the code of the Fb-Like button. I would like to send a click from another place which is a nicer button.

Nothing to do with a scam or anything like that. I would like my good looking icon to be presented and if so it will send that click to the Fb-Like box

This is the jQuery I tried (via square area on the image of my background as trigger):

```
$('.fbCustomMadeImageMap').click(function () {
    //        alert("mapFB");
    $(".fb-like").find(".pluginButton button").click();
 });
```

Now I have tested the square area to work on a click event and then I put the faceBook - jQuery find function though could not get hold of the correct element which I am supposed to send that click to..

This is the HTML of Fb-like box

What is the right refference for that element . in order to send it a click ?

**RE-Edited**

I have 2 sections of Like box... and this is the correct one i was reffering to

```
  <div class="pluginConnectButton"><div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected hidden_elem" title="">
      <div>

              <button type="submit">
                 <i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like sx_like_fav"> </i>אהבתי
            </button>
       </div>
  </div>

   <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonPressed pluginButtonInline pluginButtonX pluginConnectButtonConnected" title="">
        <div>
           <button type="submit">
              <i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOff img sp_like sx_like_ch"></i>
              <i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOn img sp_like sx_like_x" title=""></i>
         </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button

Comment: @Johan i have reEdited my post ..sorry about that mistake.