# Is facebook 'like' only button (without counter) nolonger possible?

Tags: facebook-like, standards, default, counter

Is facebook 'like' only button (without counter) no longer possible?

How do I shut off the counter +'comment-bubble'? works g+,pinit etc - on these I easily using their HTML5 code generators create asyncronous buttons without counters - don't show any counter - see www.LazyBee.biz for clarification.

Any ideas?

How do I fix this code so no counter is shown (see under comments below):

Wwhy can't facebook do like all other major social players and let user opt out of the counter-swamp?

Comment: also, just added a 'tweet' button to said url, very easy to avoid showing counter - simply untick checkbox 'display counter' on code generation page!

Comment: seems to me EVERY OTHER major social player EXCEPT FACEBOOK has a code generator which generates code without counter! Why can't Facebook follow de facto standard?! It makes me sad :(

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie. on twitter code generating page + google+ + pinterest it was SO easy to get code without counter! NOT so on facebooks code generation page :( Plz help me by rewriting this html5 that displays UNWANTED counter: <!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.Start --> <div class="fb-like" data-href="lazybee.biz " data-width="30" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div> <!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.End -->

Comment: why can't facebook do like all other major social players and let user opt out of the counter-swamp?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some people put the like button in an `<div>` and then make the width exactly the width of the button (without the counter) and put `overflow: hidden` in the CSS for the div. Basically the div acts as a matte of sorts.

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie. on twitter code generating page + google+ + pinterest it was SO easy to get code without counter! NOT so on facebooks code generation page :( Plz help me by rewriting this html5 that displays UNWANTED counter:    <!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.Start -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.lazybee.biz/ " data-width="30" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
<!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.End -->

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just create a button yourself and use the API to initiate a like. See also [How to trigger Facebook like button from custom button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button)

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie. on twitter code generating page + google+ + pinterest it was SO easy to get code without counter! NOT so on facebooks code generation page :( Plz help me by rewriting this html5 that displays UNWANTED counter:    <!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.Start -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.lazybee.biz/ " data-width="30" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
<!-- FB part2 html5 to add Like.End -->

Comment: How? what url to read? why can't facebook do like all other major social players and let user opt out of the counter-swamp?

Comment: Don't complain like that ;) And no, I cannot help you. First try to talk to the api, ie. using the [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/). If it doesn't work out, search questions on SO. If you haven't found a suitable answer, open up a new question and post your code. That's how we role on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate the Facebook like button without the counter bubble.

In the code that Facebook's generator gives you there will be a parameter called `data-layout`, depending on the options you selected it will be one of four things: `standard`, `box_count`, `button_count` or `button`.

If you use `button` it will generate a single button with no counter.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed your comment with the code supplied by Facebook. If you change it to the following it will remove the counter:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="lazybee.biz " data-width="30" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>`