# How to implement complete changed design of social network like buttons

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-like, social-networking

I'd like to customize social network like buttons like displayed on the attached picture. Is possible?[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. That's the answer. Now you can delete this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger Facebook like button from custom button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you

If you want to use addthis, read this page
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons

If you want to use sharethis, read this page. 
http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/446558-custom-buttons

And if your after being fancy and want to use your own jquery, go for sharrree, and you can customise to your hearts content.
http://sharrre.com/

Cheers
Nate