# How to make big custom social media button for like

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm making website where I need to make custom like and follow button of social media. I tried lots of thing but not able to create. 
I followed the all step from developers site of individual 
like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
and created successfully all functionality. But I'm not able to make custom button. 
I saw this in lots of website but not able to create. I want if click on custom button then popup should come from social media.

I wasted my 2 days on it. Please help if someone has some knowledge in to it.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you Post what you tried before?

Comment: Yes, first of all I made the button from facebook developers then added to my website that is working fine but I want to make custom fb button like left slide button.@hexerei software

Comment: Try googling here First: i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to change the appearance of the Like Button in any way:

> Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins

But you can use Open Graph Likes instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/