# How to make a button perform a Facebook like action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know that Facebook provides some code to add one of their like buttons to webpages, but what I need to do is create a custom button which does the same thing. So for example:

```
<input type="button" value="Like" id="fb-like"/>
```

I would like that button to send an action to like the website because I can apply custom styling to it which looks a lot better than FB's own bright blue buttons.

Is this possible? I can't find the code to make a custom like button work.

Comment: Have you ever heard about `onclick` event and Javascript ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yep, I can do that with JQuery. Where is the code to get it to perform a like? On facebook's site it says I have to include their javascript code and html which just puts a blue button on the page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'll find it on the web with "fb like button"

Comment: But beware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493988/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-button-from-custom-button

Comment: Damn it can't be done